# Reglas de formularío. Que aparezca una imagen como respuesta

Tags: php, javascript, formularios

Tengo un formulario que redirige a una página de gracias .

Ahora quisiera saber como se puede  que en la misma pagina aparezca una imagen como resultado. Relativa a un producto que reúne las características que indicó.

Comment: Podrías implementar alguna librería de alerta como https://alertifyjs.com/examples.html para mejorar la experiencia de usuario

Comment: Podrías mostrar que haz intentado y cual es el comportamiento que esperas, con el fin de poder ayudarte de forma más precisa porque sólo una de las interpretaciones que se le puede dar a tu pregunta tendría una respuesta como: **mostrar una imagen como?** simple, solamente `<img src="../ubicacion/miimagen.jpg" alt="Esta es una hermosa imagen">`

Comment: Hola. Si, son imágenes de unos 7 productos. . Que se deducen por las preferencias que se asientan en los campos del formulario,

Answer (score 0):

Puede manejar una variable booleana que cambie su valor a true cuando se reúnen las características que indicas y false cuando no, y dependiendo de el valor de esa variable con if - else muestras la imagen, puedes iniciar teniendo la imagen oculta con display:none y cambiar la propiedad según vaya cambiando la condición

Answer (score 0):

si estas usando ajax puedes hacer lo siguiente una vez envias los datos

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

       var data=.......//recoje los datos que tengas que recojer en una o varias variables 
         var url=tupagina.php
         $("form").submit(function(e){ //obtenemos el formulario

         e.preventDefault()//prevenimos el envio inmediato del formulario


        $.ajax({

         url:url,
         data:data,//envias los datos recojidos de tu formulario
         success:function(data){

           if(data=="ok"){

            $("#resultados").(html).(data);//muestras el resultado enexitoso obtenido de tu script php en un div vacio con el id resultados 

             setTimeout(function(){

               window.location.href="tupagina.php";

            },5000)//esta funcion durara 5 segundos para redireccional a la otra pagina

          }
        }


        })
       })
 })
```

notese que esto es solo un ejemplo mas o menos de como se lograria lo que quieres usando jquery y php hay muchisimas formas de hacer lo que quieres pero como dicen poray en la programacion hay muchos caminos para llegar a roma , este es uno de los ejemplos mas sencillos y entendibles espero ayudarte Exitos!!